# Problems POST-ing with pyCurl

Tags: python, webservice-client, pycurl

i'm trying to POST a file to a webservice using CURL (that's what I need to use so I can't take twisted or something else). The problem is that when using pyCurl the webservice doesn't receive the file i'm sending, as in the case commented at the bottom of the file. What am I doing wrong in my pyCurl script? Any ideeas?

Thank you very much.

```
import pycurl
import os

headers = [ "Content-Type: text/xml; charset: UTF-8; " ]
url = "http://myurl/webservice.wsdl"
class FileReader:
    def __init__(self, fp):
        self.fp = fp
    def read_callback(self, size):
        text = self.fp.read(size)
        text = text.replace('\n', '')
        text = text.replace('\r', '')
        text = text.replace('\t', '')
        text = text.strip()
        return text

c = pycurl.Curl()
filename = 'my.xml'
fh = FileReader(open(filename, 'r'))

filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
c.setopt(c.URL, url)
c.setopt(c.POST, 1)
c.setopt(c.HTTPHEADER, headers)
c.setopt(c.READFUNCTION , fh.read_callback)
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, 1)
c.setopt(c.HTTP_VERSION, c.CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0)
c.perform()
c.close()
# This is the curl command I'm using and it works
# curl -d @my.xml -0 "http://myurl/webservice.wsdl" -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8"
```

Comment: I was just wondering if you found the correct answer to your question?

Comment: What is the value of the output of `VERBOSE` to stdout?

Answer (score 8):

PyCurl seems to be an orphaned project.  It hasn't been updated in two years.  I just call command line curl as a subprocess.

```
import subprocess

def curl(*args):
    curl_path = '/usr/bin/curl'
    curl_list = [curl_path]
    for arg in args:
        # loop just in case we want to filter args in future.
        curl_list.append(arg)
    curl_result = subprocess.Popen(
                 curl_list,
                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    return curl_result 

curl('-d', '@my.xml', '-0', "http://myurl/webservice.wsdl", '-H', "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do the file upload in this manner:

c.setopt(c.HTTPPOST, [("filename.xml", (c.FORM_FILE, "/path/to/file/filename.xml"))])

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting problems like this can be a pain because it isn't always clear up front whether the problem is 1) your code, 2) the library you're using, 3) the web service -- or some combination.

It was observed already that PyCURL is not really an active project. Consider rewriting on top of [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) instead. Of the many Python libraries that speak HTTP it may be the best candidate for recreating stuff you'd do with CURL.